# editing event's functions in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

so I have started to learn Java programming(I know C#), so Im currentyly working on a simple blackjack game.
I have a basic event function when a certain panel is uploaded, this is the function:

```
private void game_panelComponentShown(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
    Update_labels();
    Start_game();
```

I've created this function with netbeans designer, the problem is that I want to move this entire function, up in the code to be near certain group of other fucntions, that helps me editing the code and make the code arranged.
The problem is that net beans marks this function with grey color, and I cant delete/move/copy this function to any where.
Do you have any suggestions how to do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you might want to stick to Java naming conventions, e.g., `updateLabels`, 'startGame`, etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks will apply it, didn't know about it

Comment: This is because the function (it's header) has been created (generated) by the Swing Designer, it doesn't allow to modify such functions, you are only allowed to change a body of this function, but not it's header nor it's place within the code.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer,I know that but Im trying to find a way to change its place withing the code. If you have any suggestions how do to it that would be great

Answer (score 0):

1. search the .java file in your project folder
2. open it use other text editor except netbeans, in windows you can use notepad++
3. move all your function with the following line which always been there after function closing } symbol.

this "//GEN-LAST:event_" line always remain after the function, don't delete it, so you still can enjoy netbeans facilities when you want to delete the component, etc.

Example :

```
    private void game_panelB(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
        Update_labels();
        Start_game();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SomeEventHereB

    private void game_panelC(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
        Update_labels();
        Start_game();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SomeEventHereC

    private void game_panelA(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
        Update_labels();
        Start_game();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SomeEventHereA
```

becomes :

```
    private void game_panelA(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
        Update_labels();
        Start_game();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SomeEventHereA

    private void game_panelB(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
        Update_labels();
        Start_game();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SomeEventHereB

    private void game_panelC(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt)
        Update_labels();
        Start_game();
    }//GEN-LAST:event_SomeEventHereC
```